# Unresolved external symbol for every glew function I use

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew

I wanted to create new OpenGl/GLEW/GLFW Visual Studio project in `64 bit`. So I downloaded glew binaries and glfw binaries. My project settings are as followed:

Additional Libraries:

- glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\x64
- glfw-3.3.bin.WIN64\lib-vc2019

Additional Dependencies:

- glew32s.lib (I dont get why its named glew32 and its in x64 folder)
- opengl32.lib
- glfw3.lib

With such setting for every glew function like `glGenBuffers` or `glUseProgram` or anything I get LNK2001 unresolved external symbol error. 
Any clue where I did a mistake?

(And since I am a new to all of these can someone explain why do I have to link opengl32.lib on 64 bit app and why there is no opengl64.lib and so on?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to link the static glew library on windows, then you've to define the `GLEW_STATIC` preprocessor definition when you compile your application.
See [Building Your Project with GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html)
and [GLEW - why should I define GLEW_STATIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741322/glew-why-should-i-define-glew-static/49741747#49741747).

If you use gnu (g++), then just add `-D GLEW_STATIC` to the build command.
In Visual Studio add `GLEW_STATIC` to the *Project properties* -> *C/C++* -> *Preprocessor* -> *Preprocessor Definitions*

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to work when I link it dynamicly (glew32.lib instead of glew32s.lib).
Still no clue why static linking didnt work out.